# Does barred in spirals galaxies like ours have the same speed (spin) as the center black hole?

Tags: black-holes, galaxies, galaxy-rotation-curve, structure-formation

In the case of old galaxies (elliptical) the black hole, like one in M87 have 2 jets. This look like polarisation pushing from central BH. In barred spiral galaxies, the bar have to cross the central black hole. Does this bar spin as the same speed as the black hole?
Do we know if BH and bar rotational speed  match (alignment)?
If ever they match, should we consider polarity as some kind of feature coming from those black holes pushing matter?
Polarity here is not positive/negative, but left/right. Something that have external influences on Galaxies, but exerted by black hole itself.
Does accretion disk bulges at bar position, if there one? (Accretion disk are more visible then black holes, present only if matter fall in.)
I understand that observations of BH are difficult, do all have some kind of left/right poles? (Like those jets in quasar, if those are black holes.)

Comment: I talk about super massive black hole here, not sure if polarity could apply at large.

Comment: "In barred spiral galaxy, this bar is cut in the middle by the central black hole." Where is this piece of misinformation from?

Comment: Sit in middle would be more precise. The bar go to the arms both side. Black hole do not cut, if this is the word you call misinformation. I will edit the question.

Comment: Galaxy's shape must share with there black hole's forces or shape. Galactic center BH seem not to obey all attitude we give to black holes in general. They do not eat everything around, They would had swallowed there's galaxy already. They seem to be well balanced with there host. Event horizon or the inside act with the outside helping galactic shape. What are those forces or shape?

Comment: Bar rotation and black hole spin have nothing to do with each other. (And the first is much, much slower than the second.)